# Get Google's global monthly searches

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I've had a look into using the Google Adwords API (PHP Library) but it seems to do a similar thing to what [The Adwords Interface](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer) does and give you **loads** of recommended keywords and their relative "Global Monthly Searches" - I just need the Global Monthly Searches for the specific keyword I'm looking for.

Is there an easy way of doing this? Perhaps even without the full blown Adwords API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the AdWords API it's possible to just request the stats for a keyword instead of a list of ideas. You need to use the TargetingIdeaService and specify a `requestType` of `STATS` instead of `IDEAS` in the selector:

Try out the PHP example at http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Fu0vUbQ37f4/trunk/examples/v201008/GetRelatedKeywords.php and replace the line:

`$selector->requestType = 'IDEAS';`

With:

`$selector->requestType = 'STATS';`

Comment: Does it cost something ($$) to use Google's Adwords account, when it's live, to do what you're talking about?