# Get the number of monthly searches for specific keywords using some API for Laravel 5.* (PHP)

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5, google-api

I found several similar questions:

- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929309/get-number-of-monthly-searches-for-specific-keywords-using-google-adwords-api-fo)
- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424564/use-google-adwords-api-with-php-to-get-keyword-cpc-and-monthly-search-volume)
- [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184411/get-googles-global-monthly-searches)

I, however, don't really understand the Google Adwords API and I am a little lost.

All I need is to send a word and get its monthly/yearly searches.

Can you please provide me with some sample code snippets or github packages for this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/keywords-performance-report - something like this?

Comment: As I've said in my question, I saw the google adwords api and I did my best trying to implement it. I got nowhere obviously. That's why I am searching for github packages, code snippets, etc...